# How to prevent infinite recursion (with Moose)?

Tags: perl, recursion, moose

In the following code fragment (Perl with Moose) there seems to be an infinite recursion:

```
has 'ORM' => ( is     => 'ro',
               isa     => 'Model::LazySQLModel',
               lazy    => 1,
               builder => 'ORM_builder' );

has 'id' => ( is        => 'ro',
              isa       => 'Int',
              lazy      => 1,
              builder   => 'id_builder',
              predicate => 'has_id',
            );

sub id_builder { $_[0]->ORM->id }

sub ORM_builder {
  my ($self) = @_;

  # FIXME: looks like infinite recursion
  if ($self->id) {
    return $self->ORM_find();
  } else {
    return $self->ORM_insert();
  }
}
```

Remark: `Model::LazySQLModel` is a tied hash which holds ID and other DB fields.

What is the right way to do this (to be sure that we prevent infinite recursion)?

Comment: It seems that replacing `if ($self->id)` with `if ($self->has_id)` is a solution

Comment: Yep. Feel free to answer your own question. Predicates do not cause builders to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing `if ($self->id)` with `if ($self->has_id)` is a solution.